# Do not get email alerts when Task is modified

Tags: list, alert

I have enabled following settings for my Task List i.e. List Settings > Advanced Settings > Send e-mail when ownership is assigned? Yes.

Now, When a task is edited or deleted, I do not get any alerts by email. Does this functionality require a custom workflow or SharePoint 2010 has an inbuilt which I am not aware of? Thx.

Comment: SPGeek thanks to your question I resolved an issue. The option was disable in advanced setting in a Task list. Thankssss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alerts on list items are handled by multiple timer jobs - you need to make sure these are NOT disabled. You can find here an detailed explanation (http://chrisdomino.com/blog/post/The-Truth-About-How-Daily-SharePoint-Alerts-Actually-Work)

Besides, people being Assigned To need to have at least Read access to the site where Alerts are configured for them, or otherwise alerts will not be sent.

If you would like however to troubleshoot you could benefit from this (excellent description, workflow, etc.) http://sharepointalert.info/troubleshooting-sharepoint-alerts

Hope it helps,
c:\Marius